# Running docker commands on remote machine through ssh

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-container

I have two machines:

- Ubuntu workstation running docker
- Macbook with Mac OS

I want to be able to run docker commands from MacOS through ssh on my Ubuntu workstation.
Docker works fine when running commands on Ubuntu.
SSH works fine (key based with entity saved).

I've tried creating a context:

```
docker context create ubuntu --docker "host=ssh://myuser@192.168.1.100"
docker context use ubuntu
docker run -it alpine sh
```

and I get:

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at http://docker. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

the same error I get when trying to:

```
docker -H ssh://myuser@192.168.1.100 run -it alpine sh
```

Nothing from the solutions I've found seems to be helping.

PS: 192.168.1.100 is only for the question. When running commands I use real IP, which is correct and not colliding with anything. Dirrect SSH is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case you can use `docker-machine`:

**Install:**

```
base=https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.16.0 &&
curl -L $base/docker-machine-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) >/tmp/docker-machine &&
sudo mv /tmp/docker-machine /usr/local/bin/docker-machine &&
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

**Run/create:**

```
docker-machine create \
  --driver generic \
  --generic-ip-address=put_here_ip_of_remote_docker \
  --generic-ssh-key ~/.ssh/id_rsa \
  vm_123
```

**Check:**

```
docker-machine ls
```

```
docker-machine ip vm_123
docker-machine inspect vm_123
```

**Use:**

```
docker-machine ssh vm_123
docker run -it alpine sh
exit
exit
eval $(docker-machine env -u)
```

**Extra tips:**

Also you can make `vm_123` as the active docker machine via this command:

```
eval $(docker-machine env vm_123)
docker run -it alpine sh
exit
eval $(docker-machine env -u)
```

and unset docker machine `vm_123` as active via this command:

```
eval $(docker-machine env -u)
```

https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/generic/

https://docs.docker.com/machine/examples/aws/

https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/

https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ssh/

Comment: I've followed your answer and I think I've found the reason why my attemps were not working. I'm not 100% sure as I did a lot of things but when creating docker-machine it was complaining that my user is not in sudoers list. So I added it. And now everything works like expected. Also I'm aceepting your answer as it all the commands that I have to run in one place. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Is you sure that ip on your Ubuntu is `192.168.1.1` ?

Because I think that its your router ip :)

Can you post `ip a` from your Ubuntu, please ?

Comment: I've replaced actual IP into 192.168.1.1 for security reasons, and I didn't think that it might be router IP. But yes I'm using correct IP, and SSH is working correctly.